# How to make input inside flexbox size to available space?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get the input to take all available space inside this flexbox but not extend beyond the width of the flexbox.

```
<div>
   <input type="number"/>
   <button>OK</button>
</div>

div
{
  display:flex;
  width:100px;
  position:relative;
  border:solid 1px #000;
}

input
{
  flex:1;
  display:block;
  border:none;
}
```

The problem is that the input is overflowing the containing flexbox div. If I set the input's width to 100% it seems to work in Chrome but fail in FF. How should this be done?

https://jsfiddle.net/y7d7Ldur/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is because the input has a default width bigger than `100px`. Add `min-width:0` to the input to fix this:

```css
div
{
  display:flex;
  width:100px;
  position:relative;
  border:solid 1px #000;
}

input
{
  flex:1;
  display:block;
  border:none;
  min-width:0;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <input type="number">
   <button>OK</button>
</div>
```

Comment: how did min-width:0 fix this issue?

Comment: Oh got it. without min-width:0 it used to take some x px
with min-width:0 it just takes the remaining flex box

Answer (score 2):

You can give the `div` a `max-width` and activate flex with `width: 0;` on `input`

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

input {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border: none;
  width: 0;
}

button {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="number"/>
  <button>OK</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

You dont need to make it a flex box.

you can just do this:

```
<div>
<input></input>
</div>

<style>
div{
width: 100px;
}
input{
min-width:100%;
margin: 0px;
}
</style>
```